# How can the probability of multiple events be summed together?

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have a scenario where probabilities of multiple ship encounters has to be calculated. Let us say that there are 4 ships in an area. The ship A has a probability of 0.4 for hitting ship B and a probability of 0.8 for hitting ship C and probability 0 that it hits the ship D. What would be a round probability of this ship hitting vessels. How can I calculate this ? Are there any theorems or related mathematical works on these.

Comment: How about the probability that A hits the fourth ship, D? Do we know that?

Comment: @MattiP. Yes let us assume that we know that as well.

Comment: I think we can assume that the probabilities of hitting B and C are independent? Meaning, the probability of hitting C doesn't depend on whether or not B has been hit.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

You have to think about **all** the possibilities. I think the logic is so that for each ship (B,C,D), ship A either hits it or not. Therefore, all possibilites are roughly summarized like so:

- A doesn't hit B; doesn't hit C and doesn't hit D
- A doesn't hit B; doesn't hit C and hits D (probability 0)
- A doesn't hit B; hits C and doesn't hit D
- A doesn't hit B; hits C and hits D (probability 0)
- A hits B; doesn't hit C and doesn't hit D
- A hits B; doesn't hit C and hits D (probability 0)
- A hits B; hits C and doesn't hit D
- A hit B; hits C and hits D (hits all other ships) (probability 0)

In principle, you have to consider all of these separately. Notice, however, that for some of these events the probability can be 0; and notice that the sum of these probabilities has to be exactly 1. With these two ideas, you can simplify the calculation.

If we denote the probability that A hits B by $P(B)$; and the probability that A hits C is $P(C)$; and we know that the probability that A doesn't hit D is 1, then the condition that the sum is 1 becomes
$$
(1-P(B))(1-P(C)) + (1-P(B))P(C) + P(B)(1-P(C)) + P(B)P(C) = 1
$$

Now we can ask ourselves: what is the probability that we're after? We want the probability that "A hits (at least one) vessel". In other words, we want the probability $(1-P(B))P(C) + P(B)(1-P(C)) + P(B)P(C)$. We can just solve for it:
$$
\begin{split}
P("\text{A hits at least one vessel}") 
&= (1-P(B))P(C) + P(B)(1-P(C)) + P(B)P(C)  \\
&= 1 - (1-P(B))(1-P(C)) \\
&= 1 - (1-0.4)(1-0.8)
\end{split}
$$